# How can I execute a shell command in php?

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec

The following command works in terminal, but I can't figure out how to use `exec()` to run it from within a PHP script.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i <(echo -e "file '/home/1.mp4'\nfile '/home/2.mp4'") -c copy -y /home/output.mp4
```

I tried a few character escape options but none worked. Any help will be appreciated.

```
 array_push($files, "file '".$local."'"); //run this twice to get both 1.mp4 and 2.mp4
 $command = 'ffmpeg -y -auto_convert 1 -f concat -i <(echo -e "'.implode('\\n', $files).'") -c copy -y /home/output.mp4';
 exec($command);

 //also tried exec(escapeshellcmd($command));
 //also tried $command = 'ffmpeg '.escapeshellarg('-y .... output.mp4');
 //also tried array_push($files, "file \'".$local."\'");
```

The error I got:

```
  sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Right, I worked out how to fix. I need to add bash -c to the command.

Comment: show us what you tried

Comment: You are probably on the right track with character escaping, but without seeing how you are using this _in your PHP code_ there's no way to tell where it's going wrong.

Comment: I see you're trying to append two files... perhaps if you used `ffmpeg -i "concat:/home/1.mp4|/home/2.mp4" ...` it might make your character escaping less tricky?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Added my code.

Comment: @Dagon Added the php code I tried to run

Comment: thanks @LiamDempsey, I have to use the concat demuxer as the protocol method won't work for my videos